# Realloc Using Way too much Memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, valgrind, realloc

I have made a minimal-working example of how to add elements to an array with realloc.  This will be expanded in a future program that has many more elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>//printf
#include <stdlib.h>//malloc, realloc

int main() {
//BEGIN REALLOCATE-ABLE ARRAY
    unsigned int *array, loop_variable;
    const unsigned int ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 4, REALLOC_INDICES = 99;
    array = malloc(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(unsigned int));
    for (loop_variable = 0; loop_variable < ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE; loop_variable++) {
        array[loop_variable] = loop_variable;
    }
//BEGIN REALLOCATION
    for (loop_variable = 1; loop_variable < REALLOC_INDICES; loop_variable++) {
        array = realloc(array,sizeof(unsigned int)*(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable));
        array[ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1] = 2*(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1);
        printf("reallocate array[%d] = %d\n",ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1,array[ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1]);
    }
//BEGIN PRINTING ARRAY VALUES
    for (loop_variable = 0; loop_variable < ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+REALLOC_INDICES-1; loop_variable++) {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n",loop_variable,array[loop_variable]);
    }
//BEGIN FREE ARRAY
    free(array); array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

This should compile on any computer with gcc or clang.  I then run this program on valgrind to ensure there are no memory leaks, and I get this:

```
==10791== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10791==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10791==   total heap usage: 99 allocs, 99 frees, 20,988 bytes allocated
==10791== 
==10791== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10791== 
==10791== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==10791== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

However, what troubles me is that I'm using 20,988 bytes for a 101-element array.  The memory use grows exponentially as the array gets bigger, instead of linearly by 4 bytes/element.

*If I'm understanding Valgrind's output correctly*, this array should have 4*101 elements = 404 bytes memory size, but *appears to use* about 50 times as much memory as it should.  This is a trivial problem for such a small program, but more meaningful programs will run out of memory on this computer.

**My question**: is this array really using 20,988 bytes, or is Valgrind double-counting the memory?

Is there a more memory-efficient way to do this?  I can't understand other examples of realloc, though I have tried to follow them as closely as I can and make this question relevant to as many users as possible.

Comment: Isn't Valgrind reporting the total sizes in `malloc` and `realloc` arguments as `total heap usage`, ignoring all `free`s?

Comment: Are you sure it's growing exponentially, rather than O(n^2)? 20988 is quite close to 4*101*101/2.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc, and family of functions, to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when using realloc(). assigned the returned value to a temp pointer.  test the temp pointer for NULL, (if NULL, then handle error, else assign array = temp pointer.   Otherwise, if realloc fails,. then the current pointer in array is lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: the final realloc loop is: realloc( 4*(4+98) )  I.E. a bit of 400 bytes.  since the final size is known, why all the looping?  malloc and realloc are 'expensive'  suggest only one malloc of the final size, followed by a loop to set the contents of the allocated memory.

Comment: @ user3629249 The program is a pathfinder for a more meaningful program where the final size is unknown.  This program is an attempt to get a C version of Perl's "push".

Comment: `20,988` is the sum of all allocations.  Not  '20,988 bytes for a 101-element array".

Comment: "The memory _use_ grows exponentially ...."  The sum of memory ever allocated in total grows exponentially (evident from code).  But how was _use_ determined?

Answer (score 5):

```
==10791==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10791==   total heap usage: 99 allocs, 99 frees, 20,988 bytes allocated
```

> is this array really using 20,988 bytes

No, it's using 0 bytes.

“allocated” obviously means “ever allocated”, including bytes that have been freed, since the amount of memory “still allocated” is zero (and another line tells you that).

Comment: The program "ever allocates" only 100 times 4 bytes. The total of all [re-]allocation requests is 20,200 bytes (that is: 4+(4+4)+(4+(4+4))+...). There is still 788 bytes missing - maybe this is overhead?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie By executing the program under Valgrind, you are **asking** it to be run in an environment where `realloc` always creates a new block and frees the old one, because this is how the programming bug of using the old pointer after calling `realloc` is found. I don't use Valgrind because I work on my own similar system, but that's how my system work, I would be surprised if Valgrind's system didn't work this way too. Besides, now that we have established that “heap usage” is only a statistic computed with a unusual algorithm, what are we arguing about?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie:  Because of alignment restrictions, `malloc()` and `realloc()` effectively return memory in discreet sizes that on every x86 implementation I've looked at are always multiples of 8 bytes.  An examination of Valgrind source code might indicate it's counting the amount of allocated memory in such chunks.  That would account for some of the discrepancy you noted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, thanks to user Pascal Cuoq, is that Valgrind will sum the memory allocations for every allocation.  This is why I was confused, and thought that realloc was using too much memory.

I thought that if you want to find the size of the array, you can comment out the line that says

```
free(array); array = NULL;
```

to intentionally introduce a memory bug, and Valgrind will output

```
==11699== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11699==    definitely lost: 408 bytes in 1 blocks
==11699==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11699==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11699==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11699==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11699== 
==11699== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==11699== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

which gives you the true size of the array at its last iteration.  There is probably a better way to do this, but my point is made.

I added improvements suggested by other users here.  I had a very difficult time finding good, minimal working examples of realloc on search engines, and for future use of anyone finding this on a search engine, this is very basic minimal working example of a good, but probably not best, how to use realloc in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>//include printf function
#include <stdlib.h>//include malloc, realloc functions

int main() {
/*BEGIN REALLOCATE-ABLE ARRAY*/
    unsigned int *array, loop_variable;
    const unsigned int ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 4, REALLOC_INDICES = 99999;
    array = malloc(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(unsigned int));
    for (loop_variable = 0; loop_variable < ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE; loop_variable++) {
        array[loop_variable] = loop_variable;
    }
/*BEGIN REALLOCATION*/
    for (loop_variable = 1; loop_variable < REALLOC_INDICES; loop_variable++) {
        array = realloc(array,sizeof(unsigned int)*(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable));
        if (array == NULL) {
            printf("Array variable %d failed to reallocate :,-(\n",loop_variable);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        array[ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1] = 2*(ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1);
        printf("reallocate array[%d] = %d\n",ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1,array[ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+loop_variable-1]);
    }
/*BEGIN PRINTING ARRAY VALUES*/
    for (loop_variable = 0; loop_variable < ORIGINAL_ARRAY_SIZE+REALLOC_INDICES-1; loop_variable++) {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n",loop_variable,array[loop_variable]);
    }
/*BEGIN FREE ARRAY*/
    free(array); array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```